# Transparent navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

I want to create a transparent navigation bar in only one of my controllers in the navigation stack. I want to stick with the system UINavigationBar for this.

My approach is the following:

In the controller which shouldn’t have transparent navigation bar:

```
- (void)setupNavBar {
    UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    if (!navBar) return;

    [navBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    navBar.shadowImage = nil;
    navBar.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;

    for (UIView *view in navBar.subviews) {
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
        view.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    }
}
```

In the controller which should have transparent nav bar:

```
- (void)setupNavBar {
    UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    if (!navBar) return;

    navBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Mark nav bar invisible
    [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    navBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    navBar.translucent = YES;
    navBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Add shadow to buttons
    Class navigationBarContentViewClass = NSClassFromString(@"_UINavigationBarContentView");
    if (navigationBarContentViewClass) {
        for (UIView *view in navBar.subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:navigationBarContentViewClass]) {
                view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
                view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9f;
                view.layer.shadowRadius = 4.f;
            }

            view.exclusiveTouch = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Seems working fine when I have only the default translucent light navigation bar, but when I set it to translucent black or to use a custom tint color, the large title background remains white:

[image: Example]

What’s the problem? How can I set the original nav bar tint color back?

Comment: In viewDidAppear of first VC did you call setupNavBar again?

Comment: I call the functions in -viewWillAppear.

Comment: have u tried putting that call in GCD main thread?

Comment: -viewWillAppear is called on the main thread as far as I know.

Comment: what if u remove the shadow manual settings in that code?

Comment: Doesn’t matter. Still does not work. It appears that only the large title appearance is affected.

Comment: You should check which view is the view in navBar subview for the large one. Anyway, things like this bound to happen when you subclass (Apple actually discourage from doing this). Even if you able to make it work in this iOS, when new iOS comes, they normally break